# Templated function called without template provided?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this

```
#include "Division_Euclidean_space.h"

float find_diameter_exact(const int N, const int D,
                              const std::vector<float>& v) {
  d = squared_Eucl_distance(v, offset, offset + D, i * D + D);
  ...
}
```

where I was actually planning to make a templated method, since my vector is going to support any numerical data type.

So, in the header file included I have:

```
template<typename T>
T squared_Eucl_distance(const std::vector<T> &p, size_t start1,
                                size_t end1, size_t start2) {
   ...
}
```

Shouldn't I am getting an error saying that I didn't provide `T` for `squared_Eucl_distance()`.

---

PS

Funny related [pic](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/my-code-works-and-i-don-t-know-why-4.png).

Comment: `T` is deduced from the function arguments.

Comment: _"Funny related pic."_ Most of the time I'm worried about the other way round ;) ...

Comment: I guessed that juanchopanza, but I wasn't sure! @πάνταῥεῖ me too, but I didn't want to write it in my answer, in order not to become "spam". ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Template type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) is not an "easy" thing, but in your case that's easy: when you pass a `std::vector<something>`, the compiler will deduce from `std::vector<T>` that `T === something`

Your function is so instantiated as

```
something squared_Eucl_distance(const std::vector<something> &p, size_t start1,
                                size_t end1, size_t start2)
```

whatever `something` is.

You will get an error if you pass as a first parameter something other than a `std::vector`

Comment: Bella risposta! I will accept it as soon as the time limit passes. Grazie :) // lived in Lugano for some time

Comment: Oh I have a question, template type deduction happens in compile time or in run time? Is it better (in situations like the one posted) to let the deduction to happen automatically or we should prefer to give the type ourselves?

Comment: @g.samares Compile time.  You shoud rake a `std::vector<T,A> const&` and let both `T` and `A` be deduced.

Comment: Yakk comment is correct. My sample works because `A`, is left unspecified, defaults to `std::allocator<T>`, according to `std::vector` declaration inside the `<vector>` C++ header.